# Use model attribute as ng-if condition, get error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

The error is when I use model's attribute as a condition in angular ng-if directive. It occurs an error which is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

And my html is:

```
 <div class="item-input-wrapper">
   <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
   <input type="search" ng-model="keywords" placeholder="Search" >
   <button ng-if="keywords.length"
    class="button button-icon ion-ios7-close-outline input-button"
    ng-click="clearSearchWords()">
   </button>
 </div>
```

I have tried to copy this code in an new ionic project, and it can be executed in other project perfectly.
Ng-if is a build-in angular directive. Why it could result in different outputs?
And is that any approach to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the `ng-if`? The error report shows a `then` so it should be related to a missing promise.

Comment: @pasine not sure, but when I remove <button></button>, the error will disappear. Fortunately, when I use bower update angular, the problem fixed, even new angular version is same as original one. So it may be because of the angular itself

Comment: Can you post the javascript function where you get error?

Comment: @pasine, it is from either "angular-animate" or "angular". I forget which one is correct, but definitely one of above.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `keywords` is not available when you check its length. Try to put `keywords && keywords.length` in the ng-if condition.

Comment: @pasine actually, the code works but the problem is after I delete all characters, the error occurs.That means there will be no errors when keywords equal to undefined or "1", or "anything else". Once keywords equal to "", the error occurs.

Comment: What if you put `ng-if = 0`? Does it rise the error? You should put more code, by the way, it is really hard to guess the error in the blind.